# Saving only a particular piece of state in localStorage w/ Redux

Tags: javascript, object, redux, local-storage

How to save in localStorage using Redux, only a particular piece of state?

For example, my state in **list** reducer is defined as follows:

```
state = {
    companies: [],
    currentDisplay: '',
    recordNotFound: false,
  }
```

This is my combineReducer file:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  list: listReducer,
  form: formReducer
})
```

localStorage.js:

```
export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state')
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState)
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined
  }
}

export const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state)
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState)
  } catch (err) {
    // to define
  }
}
```

And after browser reloads I want only `companies: [{obj1}, {obj2}, ...]` array to be preloaded and the rest of state reset to default values f.e. `currentDisplay: ''` to be equal ''.

Right now responsible for this operation code looks like this:

```
store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState({
    list: store.getState().list
  })
})
```

And it stores the whole list obviously... 
I guess I could easily reset these parameters in React using setState(), but would like to do this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save just the `companies` parameter on `localStorage` if you don't need the other parameters to be loaded.

```
store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState({
    companies: store.getState().list.companies
  })
})
```

Comment: Hey Tiago its unfortunately not that easy. I was trying this before. In this case my initial state after browser reloads looks like this:

   `list: [{...},{...}]`

and I would like it to have such structure:

    `list: { companies: [{...},{...}], nextParam: ' ', nextParamm: ' '}`

Comment: I didn't understand the reason to store the other params if you don't need to use them.  But you can return just `companies` array from `loadState` if you want by doing `return JSON.parse(serializedState).companies`

Comment: Yes it was exactly what I was looking for. Thx a lot! :)
The other params are exemplary. They perform as flags and filters f.e.